# java package which includes its own JRE

Tags: java, jmeter, perfmon, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to get the serveragent from perfmon for jmeter running on a Windows Server where i **cant**  install Java the description below descripes how to do but i cant read out what ment is with "create yourself the Agent package which includes ist own JRE?" i ve downloaded the newest file from java.com but its a installer was that ment with it?

Ref: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMonAgent

> The agent is written in Java, so you will need JRE 1.4+ to run it.
>   Note you can create yourself the agent package which includes its own
>   JRE so you don't have to install java on the server (We tested it on
>   windows platform). To do this, just create a JRE folder in the agent
>   folder and copy one installed JRE inside. Change the java command
>   inside the .bat file to the path to the java executable and it will
>   work.

Comment: Your question is a big sentence. I can't understand it. Try using dots and breaking the sentences.

Comment: I think the description in of PerfMonAgent want to say: "Java doesn't need to be installed via an installer - it is also possible to just copy the jre folder of an existing installation into the agent folder folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the Java on another machine (JDK+JRE).
2. Copy contents of folder in Windows > Program Files > Java > jre-XXXX to the agent folder
3. Edit the PerfMon agent .bat file and change it to match the java in the new jre folder you created at previous step